# How to create a tree by using nodes that point to next brother in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, tree, nodes

I made a class (shown below) to create a tree where nodes point to the first brother on his own right and the first son (graphically the one on the extreme left).
**How can i generate and link nodes correctly inside a ***for*** loop?**

So the first iteration of the loop needs to generate and link the first son node to the parent node, while each of the following iterations should generate and link a new node to be the brother of the previous one

```
final class Node { 
    private Node firstSon = null;
    private int data;
    private Node brotherDX = null;

    public Nodo(Nodo firstSon, int data, Nodo brotherDX) {
        this.data = data;
        this.brotherDX = brotherDX;
        this.firstSon = firstSon;
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    private Node rootNode = new Node(null, 0, null)
    
    //for cicle goes here
}
```

I'll attach a [quick drawing of how the tree should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jaV.png) :
The nodes contain:
*LIGHT BLUE* - link to first son
*WHITE* - data of the node
*GREEN* - link to brother on the right
The purple lines show what the actual shape of the tree should be in terms of parenting of the nodes.

Comment: "How can i create and link the nodes correctly inside a for cicle" - by this you mean that you want to generate and link Nodes inside the for-loop? And what are the rules for adding elements to the tree?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. I edited the post to be more clear

Comment: That actually creates more questions. The tree is a connected acyclic undirected graph. These purple lines neither fit into this definition nor in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a data structure where there is one parent node (with the firstSon pointer pointing towards the first "child" node) and a lot of child nodes, each of which point to the next using the brotherDX pointer, so either brotherDX or firstSon goes unused? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just have one pointer for both (which would, incidentally, be a singly linked list)?

Either way, the logic for adding nodes the way you want them to is fairly simple:

```
Node start = new Node(null, 0, null);
Node temp = new Node(null, 1, null);
start.firstSon = temp;
for(int i=2;i<=AMOUNT_OF_NODES;i++){
    temp.brotherDX = new Node(null, i, null);
    temp = temp.brotherDX;
}
```

Comment: I know, I pointed out in the description above that this would just be a singly (it's singly, not doubly linked!) linked list. However, this is what OP was asking for (from what I could gather) - maybe there's a language barrier here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's what i was looking for!
Because it's a tree and can be expanded, nodes can have both a link to the firstChild and the brother on the right; sorry for my english, i definitely wasn't clear enough... i edited the post and added a picture to be more precise.